# Notification saved data on database only shows when notification recieves in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

I am saving my notification coming data in sqflite database now i want to show that data in my notification screen on the basis of student selection all my student regno are showing correct on print statement but what i am facing the issue is i have notification upto 20 but when i launch my notification screen its shows no data available and when notification is recieve for a particular student then for that particular student notification is getting shown while on tap to notification and navigate to my notification screen but if i remove the app from background again when i launch notification screen it again shows no notifications available i am able to see my notifications only when i recieved the notifications and i am showing notifications on the basis of student select by tapping on avatar and choosing student from there if avatar is not tapped then notification is shown for first index student but i am able to see that list only whwn i recieve notifications.

This is my database helper class

```
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';

class NotificationData {
  int id;
  String title;
  String content;
  String regno;

  NotificationData(
      {required this.id,
      required this.title,
      required this.content,
      required this.regno});

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {'id': id, 'title': title, 'content': content, 'regno': regno};
  }

  factory NotificationData.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return NotificationData(
        id: map['id'],
        title: map['title'],
        content: map['content'],
        regno: map['regno']);
  }
}

class NotificationDatabaseHelper {
  static const _databaseName = "notifications.db";
  static const _databaseVersion = 1;

  static const table = 'notifications_table';

  static const columnId = 'id';
  static const columnTitle = 'title';
  static const columnContent = 'content';
  static const columnRegno = 'regno';

  static Database? _database;

  Future<void> init() async {
    final documentsDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final path = join(documentsDirectory.path, _databaseName);
    _database = await openDatabase(
      path,
      version: _databaseVersion,
      onCreate: _onCreate,
    );
  }

  Future _onCreate(Database db, int version) async {
    await db.execute('''
    CREATE TABLE $table (
      $columnId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
      $columnTitle TEXT NOT NULL,
      $columnContent TEXT NOT NULL,
      $columnRegno TEXT NOT NULL
    )
  ''');
  }

  Future<int> insertNotification(NotificationData notification) async {
    final db = _database;
    try {
      if (db != null) {
        final result = db.insert(table, notification.toMap(),
            conflictAlgorithm: ConflictAlgorithm.replace);
        print("Insertion result: $result");
        return result;
      } else {
        // Handle the case when the database is not initialized
        print('Database is not initialized. Insertion failed.');
        return -1; // Return a default value or an error code
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error inserting notification: $e");
      return -1;
    }
  }

  Future<List<NotificationData>> getNotifications(String regno) async {
    final db = _database;
    if (db == null) {
      return [];
    }
    final List<Map<String, dynamic>> maps = await db.query(table,
        orderBy: '$columnId DESC',
        // limit: limit,
        // offset: offset,
        where: '$columnRegno =?',
        whereArgs: [regno]);

    return List.generate(maps.length, (index) {
      return NotificationData.fromMap(maps[index]);
    });
  }
}
 Here i am doing all the functionality regarding to the database.


/* Below is my notification service class using firebase where i am doing all the functionality to insert notification to database showing notification using flutter_local_notification plugin */


import 'dart:io';

import 'dart:math';

import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

import '../database/database_helper.dart';
import '../notification/view/notification_screen.dart';
import '../notification/view/view_model/notification_refresh_data.dart';

class NotificationServices {
  FirebaseMessaging messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
  final NotificationDatabaseHelper _databaseHelper =
      NotificationDatabaseHelper();

  String? token;
  String? backgroundToken;

  final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  void initLocalNotification(
      BuildContext context, RemoteMessage message) async {
    var androidInitializationSettings =
        const AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');
    var iosInitializationSettings = const DarwinInitializationSettings();

    var initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(
        android: androidInitializationSettings, iOS: iosInitializationSettings);
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(
      initializationSettings,
      onDidReceiveNotificationResponse: (details) {
        print('Manoj');
        handleMessage(context, message);
      },
    );
  }

  void requestNotificationPermission() async {
    NotificationSettings settings = await messaging.requestPermission(
        alert: true,
        announcement: true,
        carPlay: true,
        criticalAlert: true,
        provisional: true,
        sound: true,
        badge: true);
    if (settings.authorizationStatus == AuthorizationStatus.authorized) {
      print('User granted permission');
    } else if (settings.authorizationStatus ==
        AuthorizationStatus.provisional) {
      print('User granted provisional permission');
    } else {
      print('User denied permission');
    }
  }

  Future<String> getDeviceToken() async {
    token = await messaging.getToken();
    updateUserToken();

    return token!;
  }

  void isTokenRefresh() {
    messaging.onTokenRefresh.listen((event) {
      event.toString();
      print('refresh');
    });
  }

  Future<void> updateUserToken() async {
    final pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final url =
        Uri.parse('http://demoapp.citronsoftwares.com/api/User/UpdateToken');
    final body = {
      'mobno': pref.getString('mobno').toString(),
      'fcmtoken': token,
      'imei': '',
    };
    try {
      final response = await http.post(url, body: body);

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        // Request successful
        print(response.body);
        print('Token updated successfully');
      } else {
        // Request failed
        print('Failed to update token. Status code: ${response.statusCode}');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }

  void showNotification(RemoteMessage message, BuildContext context) async {
    AndroidNotificationChannel androidNotificationChannel =
        AndroidNotificationChannel(Random.secure().nextInt(100000).toString(),
            'High Importance Notification',
            importance: Importance.max);
    AndroidNotificationDetails androidNotificationDetails =
        AndroidNotificationDetails(
      androidNotificationChannel.id.toString(),
      androidNotificationChannel.name.toString(),
      channelDescription: 'Your channel description',
      importance: Importance.max,
      priority: Priority.high,
      ticker: 'ticker',
      playSound: true,
    );

    const DarwinNotificationDetails darwinNotificationDetails =
        DarwinNotificationDetails(
            presentAlert: true, presentBadge: true, presentSound: true);

    NotificationDetails notificationDetails = NotificationDetails(
        android: androidNotificationDetails, iOS: darwinNotificationDetails);

    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
      0,
      message.data['msgtype'] ?? '', // Use msgtype as the title
      message.data['content'] ?? '',
      notificationDetails,
    );
    try {
      NotificationData notification = NotificationData(
        id: DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch,
        title: message.data['msgtype'] ?? '',
        content: message.data['content'] ?? '',
        regno: message.data['regno'] ?? '',
      );

      print("Inserting notification into database");

      int insertionResult =
          await _databaseHelper.insertNotification(notification);
      print('Insertion result: $insertionResult');

      // ... Rest of the notification handling code ...
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error inserting notification: $e");
    }

    // ignore: use_build_context_synchronously
    Provider.of<NotificationRefreshProvider>(context, listen: false).refresh();
  }

  void firebaseInit(BuildContext context) {
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((message) {
      print("message data is :${message.data.toString()}");
      if (Platform.isAndroid) {
        initLocalNotification(context, message);
        showNotification(message, context);
      } else {
        showNotification(message, context);
      }

      NotificationData notification = NotificationData(
          id: DateTime.now()
              .millisecondsSinceEpoch, // You can generate a unique ID based on your requirements
          title: message.data['msgtype'] ?? '',
          content: message.data['content'] ?? '',
          regno: message.data['regno'] ?? '');

      // print("Inserting notification into database");

      // _databaseHelper.insertNotification(notification);
      // print('selected student regno of manoj parent');
      // print(message.data['regno'] ?? '');
    });
  }

  void handleMessage(BuildContext context, RemoteMessage message) {
    if (message.data.containsKey('content')) {
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const NotificationScreen()),
      );
    }
  }

  void setupInteractMessage(BuildContext context) async {
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((event) async {
      event.data.containsKey('content') ? handleMessage(context, event) : '';
    });
  }

  void showNotificationInBackground(RemoteMessage message) async {
    AndroidNotificationChannel androidNotificationChannel =
        AndroidNotificationChannel(Random.secure().nextInt(100000).toString(),
            'High Importance Notification',
            importance: Importance.max);
    AndroidNotificationDetails androidNotificationDetails =
        AndroidNotificationDetails(
      androidNotificationChannel.id.toString(),
      androidNotificationChannel.name.toString(),
      channelDescription: 'Your channel description',
      importance: Importance.high,
      priority: Priority.high,
      ticker: 'ticker',
      playSound: true,
    );

    const DarwinNotificationDetails darwinNotificationDetails =
        DarwinNotificationDetails(
            presentAlert: true, presentBadge: true, presentSound: true);

    NotificationDetails notificationDetails = NotificationDetails(
        android: androidNotificationDetails, iOS: darwinNotificationDetails);

    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
      0,
      message.data['msgtype'] ?? '',
      message.data['content'] ?? '',
      notificationDetails,
    );
  }
}
 And now the final part of my code my ui part of a code below.......


Widget buildCard(NotificationData notification, BuildContext context) {
  if (notification.title == 'MSG') {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Container(
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(2),
                  topRight: Radius.circular(20),
                  bottomRight: Radius.circular(20),
                  bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                ),
                color: Colors.green),
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
              child: Text(
                notification.content,
                style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 12),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          // Add other widgets as needed for "MSG" type notification
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
  // If the title is "IMAGE," return an image widget
  else if (notification.title == 'IMAGE') {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
          children: [
            Image.network(
              'http://${notification.content}',
              height: 200,
              width: 200,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  } else {
    return Container();
  }
}

class NotificationScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const NotificationScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<NotificationScreen> createState() => _NotificationScreenState();
}

class _NotificationScreenState extends State<NotificationScreen> {
  int? schoolId;
  int? sessionId;
  String? mobno;
  Stm? selectedStudent;
  bool tap = false;
  bool avatarTap = false;
  bool _dataLoaded = false;
  bool _isLoading = true;

  // bool isLoading = true;
  var attendanceProvider;
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> _attendanceList = [];
  var attendance;
  String? feeDetail;
  String? dueFeeWebView;

  void _showStudentList(BuildContext context, List<Stm> students) {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          shape:
              RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
          backgroundColor: Colors.grey[900],
          title: const Text(
            'Select Student',
            style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600, fontSize: 14),
          ),
          content: Container(
            width: double.maxFinite,
            height: 200,
            child: ListView.separated(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              separatorBuilder: (context, index) => const Divider(),
              itemCount: students.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                final student = students[index];
                return Container(
                  height: 35,
                  child: ListTile(
                    dense: true,
                    splashColor: Colors.indigo,
                    title: Text(
                      student.stuName ?? '',
                      style: const TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                          fontSize: 12),
                    ),
                    onTap: () async {
                      final pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
                      print(
                          'before remove ${pref.getString('attendanceRegNo')}');
                      print(
                          'before remove ${pref.getString('attendanceStudentName')}');
                      pref.remove('attendanceRegNo');
                      pref.remove('attendanceStudentName');
                      pref.remove('attendanceStudentClass');
                      pref.remove('attendanceStudentRoll');
                      pref.remove('attendanceStudentPhoto');
                      pref.setString(
                          'attendanceRegNo', student.regNo.toString());
                      pref.setString(
                          'attendanceStudentName', student.stuName.toString());
                      pref.setString('attendanceStudentClass',
                          student.className.toString());
                      pref.setString(
                          'attendanceStudentRoll', student.rollNo.toString());
                      pref.setString(
                          'attendanceStudentPhoto', student.photo.toString());
                      print(
                          'after remove ${pref.getString('attendanceRegNo')}');
                      print(
                          'after remove ${pref.getString('attendanceStudentName')}');

                      setState(() {
                        selectedStudentRegno = student.regNo.toString();
                        avatarTap = true;
                        Provider.of<StudentProvider>(context, listen: false)
                            .selectStudent(index);
                        _notifications.clear(); // Clear old notifications
                        _pageNumber = 1;
                      });
                      _loadNotifications();
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    },
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  int mobile = 9670600331;
  int? mobNo;

  String userType = '';
  String selectedStudentRegno = '';

  Future<void> initializeData() async {
    await preference();
    _loadNotifications();
  }

  Future<void> preference() async {
    final pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    schoolId = pref.getInt('schoolid') ?? 0;
    userType = pref.getString('userType').toString();
    print(userType);
    print(schoolId);
    sessionId = pref.getInt('sessionid') ?? 0;
    print(sessionId);
    mobno = pref.getString('mobno');

    print(mobno);

    if (userType == 'Teacher') {
      // ignore: use_build_context_synchronously
      Provider.of<MenuViewModel>(context, listen: false)
          .fetchTeacherInfo(mobile);
    } else if (userType == 'Parent') {
    } else {}
  }

  final NotificationDatabaseHelper _databaseHelper =
      NotificationDatabaseHelper();
  List<NotificationData> _notifications = [];
  int _pageNumber = 1;
  final int _pageSize = 15; // Number of notifications to load per page

  Future<void> _loadNotifications() async {
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = true;
    });
    final studentProvider =
        // ignore: use_build_context_synchronously
        Provider.of<StudentProvider>(context, listen: false);

    final student = studentProvider.profile;
    final selectedStudentIndex = studentProvider.selectedIndex;
    final students = student?.stm ?? [];
    final selectedStudentRegno = students[selectedStudentIndex].regNo ?? '';
    print('selectedStudentRegno is $selectedStudentRegno');

    // final offset = (_pageNumber - 1) * _pageSize;
    _notifications =
        await _databaseHelper.getNotifications(selectedStudentRegno.toString());
    print('notifications is $_notifications');
    setState(() {
      // _notifications.addAll(notifications);
      _isLoading = false;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _loadNotifications();
    initializeData();

    final notificationProvider =
        Provider.of<NotificationRefreshProvider>(context, listen: false);
    notificationProvider.addListener(_handleRefresh);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    final menuProvider = Provider.of<MenuViewModel>(context);

    final studentProvider = Provider.of<StudentProvider>(context);
    var navigatedSelectedStudent = Provider.of<DashBoardViewModel>(context).stm;
    final student = studentProvider.profile;
    final selectedStudentIndex = studentProvider.selectedIndex;
    final students = student?.stm ?? [];
    final selectedStudentName = students.isNotEmpty
        ? students[selectedStudentIndex].stuName ?? 'N/A'
        : 'N/A';
    final selectedStudentClass = students.isNotEmpty
        ? students[selectedStudentIndex].className ?? 'N/A'
        : 'N/A';
    final selectedStudentRoll = students.isNotEmpty
        ? students[selectedStudentIndex].rollNo ?? 'N/A'
        : 'N/A';

    final teacherInfo = menuProvider.teacherInfo;
    final teacherName = teacherInfo?.tname ?? 'N/A';
    final teacherEmail = teacherInfo?.email ?? 'N/A';
    final teacherPhoto = teacherInfo?.photo.toString();
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        toolbarHeight: 70,
        titleSpacing: 2,
        backgroundColor: Colors.indigo[900],
        title: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            userType == "Teacher"
                ? const SizedBox(
                    width: 15,
                  )
                : const SizedBox.shrink(),
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                if (userType != "Teacher") {
                  _showStudentList(context, students);
                }
                setState(() {
                  tap = false;
                });
              },
              child: userType == 'Teacher'
                  ? CircleAvatar(
                      radius: 25,
                      backgroundImage: NetworkImage(teacherPhoto.toString()),
                    )
                  : userType == 'Parent'
                      ? CircleAvatar(
                          radius: 25,
                          backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                              students[selectedStudentIndex].photo.toString()),
                        )
                      : const CircleAvatar(
                          radius: 25,
                          backgroundImage:
                              AssetImage('assets/images/user_profile.png'),
                        ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 3.0),
                    child: Text(
                      userType == 'Teacher'
                          ? 'Name:$teacherName'
                          : userType == 'Parent'
                              ? selectedStudentName.isNotEmpty
                                  ? 'Name:$selectedStudentName'
                                  : ''
                              : '',
                      style: const TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                          fontSize: 12),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    userType == 'Teacher'
                        ? 'Email: $teacherEmail'
                        : userType == 'Parent'
                            ? selectedStudentClass.isNotEmpty
                                ? 'Class:$selectedStudentClass'
                                : 'Class:N/A'
                            : 'Class:N/A',
                    style: const TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                        fontSize: 12),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    userType == 'Teacher'
                        ? ''
                        : userType == 'Parent'
                            ? selectedStudentRoll.isNotEmpty
                                ? 'Roll:$selectedStudentRoll'
                                : 'Roll:N/A'
                            : 'Roll:N/A',
                    style: const TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                        fontSize: 12),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
      body: _buildNotificationList(),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildNotificationList() {
    if (_isLoading) {
      return const Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      );
    } else if (_notifications.isEmpty) {
      return const Center(
        child: Text(
          'No notifications are available.',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
        ),
      );
    } else {
      return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: _notifications.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          // if (index == _notifications.length) {
          //   return _buildLoadMoreButton();
          // }

          // else {
          //   final notification = _notifications[index];
          //   return buildCard(notification, context);
          // }
          final notification = _notifications[index];
          return buildCard(notification, context);
        },
      );
    }
  }

  Widget _buildLoadMoreButton() {
    final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    if (_notifications.isEmpty || _notifications.length % _pageSize != 0) {
      return SizedBox(
        height: size.height * 0.035,
        child: const Center(
            child: Text(
          'No more data available.',
          style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.redAccent,
              fontSize: 16,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
        )),
      );
    } else {
      return TextButton(
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            _pageNumber++; // Load the next page
          });
          _loadNotifications();
        },
        child: Text(
          'Load More',
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.indigo[900]),
        ),
      );
    }
  }

  void _handleRefresh() async {
    if (mounted) {
      setState(() {
        _notifications.clear();
        _pageNumber = 1;
        _isLoading = true;
        _loadNotifications();
      });

      final notifications =
          await _databaseHelper.getNotifications(selectedStudentRegno);
      print('notifications is $notifications');

      setState(() {
        _notifications.addAll(notifications);
        _isLoading = false; // Hide loader after refreshing
      });
    }
  }
}

I am not able to recognize where i am doing misstake why i am able to show my notification list only and only when new notification is recieved.
```